# In hibernate how to set status for various table objects

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two objects, Customer and Store.  I would like a user (from a user table) to be able to specify a customer or store as  "preferred".  I would then be able to see a list of users who prefer different stores or customers.  Is this possible with a hibernate mapping?

What would the table structure look if a status of preferred could be set on either customer of store per user?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. A status just needs an additional field. What does being preferred mean for a Store? And for a Customer?

Comment: I would like to see which customers and stores are preferred for a user.  I think this means a new table with either the store or customer id and also the user id.  I would then be able to see all prepared stores/customers for a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a User has many preferred Stores, and a Store is the preferred store of many users. This is thus a ManyToMany association between User and Store.

Just map it as explained [in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e11402):

```
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Store> preferredStores  = new HashSet<Store>(0);
}

public class Store {
    // necessary only if you want the association to be bidirectional:
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "preferredStores")
    private Set<User> preferringUsers = new HashSet<User>(0);
}
```

Comment: what about Customers?  Would I use some sort of polymorphism to get a set of customers and stores?

Comment: Why would you mix the two entities. They're different and have nothing in common, at least I guess so. So simply add another ManyToMany association between User and Customer.